# Sequential comunication between parent/child processes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronous

I need to establish a dialog between parent and child processes in node.

I started with following:

```
var child = cp.fork(__dirname + '/Child',[],{silent: true});
```

Then set up an event handler on parent:

```
child.stdout.on('data', processChildResponses);
```

Child listens to stdin and answers writing to stdout. Parent writes to child stdin to send commands:

```
child.stdin.write("a command...\n");
```

Then I need to send a variable number of commands to child, some require response, others don't. For those that require response, I must wait for it (let's assume forever to make it simple), process the answer and send another command.

Child was simple because it only waits for a command, answers it and awaits another. So no problem there. But I'm having many problems with parent. Any ideas?

It's an incredibly simple task in java or c# but I would like to make it all in node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [child.send() (in parent)/process.send() (in child)](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle)? That way you don't have to worry about buffering and parsing stdout and whatnot.

Comment: Its a requirement to use stdin/stdout.